# How, and if, to use server side in stripe new library @stripe/react-stripe-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

My goal is to create a simple payment page for a product.

In the official docs it says that a generation of a token is required on the server-side in order to create a transaction, using:

```js
stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: req.body.amount,
  currency: 'usd'
})
```

and using the returned key to create a transaction.

However, some other official examples use only client-side, like this:

```
const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
  type: 'card',
  card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
})
```

Without the server key `stripe.confirmCardPayment('{CLIENT_SECRET}', {`

The docs say `CLIENT_SECRET` is required but there are examples without it.

Any idea why and what is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you use Stripe's new [client-only Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client) there's no way to process payments in custom Stripe integrations without some server-side code.

As you noticed, the official [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react) for React Stripe.js only include client-side code. However, the code samples on this page don't represent a full integration required in order to process a payment. The samples only demonstrate how you would collect and tokenize credit card details in the frontend with React Stripe.js and the [createPaymentMethod](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method) function. The docs were written this way to make it easier to follow along and run the code samples in a browser without having to setup a server.

A good place to start to get an idea of what APIs are involved in end-to-end payment integrations would be:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment

(**tip** each code sample in the above guide has a `React` version that you can tab into)

If you're interested in seeing a full working integration that builds off of those React examples, I would recommend checking out the following demo that we built for a recent developer office hours episode:

https://github.com/tmarek-stripe/demo-react-stripe-js

Specifically, I would recommend reviewing the server-side portion [(here)](https://github.com/tmarek-stripe/demo-react-stripe-js/blob/master/pages/api/payment_intents.js) that creates a payment intent, and the client-side portion [(here)](https://github.com/tmarek-stripe/demo-react-stripe-js/blob/master/components/CheckoutForm.jsx#L56-L82) that creates a payment method and confirms the payment intent.

That's a lot to review! If you prefer, you can just watch the video where we go over how to create an (almost complete) integration with React Stripe.js:

[React Stripe.js - Developer Office Hours | Youtube](https://youtu.be/w1oLdAPyuok)

Once the basics are covered I would recommend reviewing another sample for a more complete end-to-end integration:

[Type-safe Payments with Next.js, TypeScript, and Stripe](http://Type-safe%20Payments%20with%20Next.js,%20TypeScript,%20and%20Stripe)

When reviewing this complete integration note how you don't need to create a payment method manually when using Stripe.js. It's optional because a successful payment intent will automatically create a payment method for you.

A payment intent gets created server-side:

```
// Create a PaymentIntent with the specified amount.
const response = await fetchPostJSON('/api/payment_intents', {
  amount: input.customDonation
});
```

https://github.com/stripe-samples/nextjs-typescript-react-stripe-js/blob/master/components/ElementsForm.tsx#L84-L88

And confirmed client-side without any `createPaymentMethod` calls needed!

```
const cardElement = elements!.getElement(CardElement);

// Use your card Element with other Stripe.js APIs
const { error, paymentIntent } = await stripe!.confirmCardPayment(
  response.client_secret,
  {
    payment_method: {
      card: cardElement!,
      billing_details: { name: input.cardholderName }
    }
  }
);
```

https://github.com/stripe-samples/nextjs-typescript-react-stripe-js/blob/master/components/ElementsForm.tsx#L99-L110

In a nutshell:

- a complete Stripe integration will usually involve some server-side
  code (unless you use [client-only Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client))
- in order to process a payment you need to [create a payment
  intent server-side](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create)
- payment intents are usually [confirmed client-side](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment)
- it's optional to create a payment method client-side because one will get created automatically if a payment intent succeeds

I hope this helps!